# Binding a Style Resource Dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-7, expression-blend

Is there any way to dynamically bind the resource style of a rectangle ?

The following works:

```
<Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0,0,8" Fill="{Binding RectangleColor}" />
```

So each list item has a different color based on its type.

The problem is that i don't like simple colors and i would like them to follow a style resource. Unfortunately this has to be done dynamically.

Trying this didnt work:

```
<Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="0,0,0,8" Style="{Binding RectangleStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you want a DataTemplateSelector.  Of course, these don't exist in Silverlight.  It seems like everyone with a blog has a way to implement it.  [Here](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector) is a WP7 version.  If you're running WP7.1 you might run into a little bit of trouble that is covered by [this stack overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219829/datatemplateselector-in-wp7-mango)

Comment: Actually I have the DataTemplate ready and its working correctly. In my case, dynamically assigning DataTemplate is not an option since always all the items are the same (the list is the same) what i need to change dynamically is the Style Resource Template of each item inside the list's DataTemplate.

And once again - binding text on some values (textblocks etc) or the fill color of the rectangle is easy.. It's complicated for me when it comes to dynamically assigning a Style to it (like theme since i would like to use better colors/effects rather that the normal ones)

Comment: You can use this same solution with styles.  You could also create multiple data templates that differ only by this style.  Unfortunately the bottom line is there is pure XAML way to do this: it will involve code.  The closest solution is Silverlight 5's implicit data templates, but even that's not yet available on the phone platform.

Comment: I am afraid that what you are saying is not an option...
Keep in mind that that i have a DataTemplate already and i need to change the style of one element in this DataTemplate.

Comment: It's impossible to proceed without more information: what are you trying to do, what does your code look like, etc.